# How do I expose ingress to my local machine? (minikube on windows)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have two deployments

deployment 1

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: first-service
spec:
  selector:
    key: app1
  ports:
    - port: 81
      targetPort: 5050

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: first-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ocr
        image: ocr_app
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5050
```

deployment 2

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: second-service
spec:
  selector:
    key: app2
  ports:
    - port: 82
      targetPort: 5000

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: second-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: app2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: app2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ner
        image: ner_app
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

After enabling ingress on minikube I applied ingess

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: demo.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /ocr
        backend:
          serviceName: first-service
          servicePort: 81
      - path: /ner
        backend:
          serviceName: second-service
          servicePort: 82
```

In my hosts file I have

```
192.168.177.71  demo.local
```

Where `192.168.177.71` is my current minikube ip

I then ran this command

```
kubectl port-forward nginx-ingress-controller-6fc5bcc8c9-p6mvj 3000:80 --namespace kube-system
```

And in the console is outputs

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:3000 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:3000 -> 80
```

But when I make a request to `demo.local:3000/ocr` using postman there is no response

> Could not get any response There was an error connecting to
>   demo.local:3000.

EDIT:  using `minikube service first-service` gives this output

```
PS D:\docker> minikube service first-service
|-----------|---------------|-------------|--------------|
| NAMESPACE |     NAME      | TARGET PORT |     URL      |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|--------------|
| default   | first-service |             | No node port |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|--------------|
* service default/first-service has no node port
```

Comment: Just to clear some thoughts. You are using Kubernetes 1.16+. Did you enable ingress in minikube `minikube addons enable ingress`? You have issue only with `/ocr` or also with `/ner`?

Comment: @PjoterS yes enabled ingress, same issue on both paths

Comment: Having .svc.cluster.local and .local endpoints in the hosts file you just need to have the ingress controller running (ngingx for example) and a default or matching ingressClass in the definition

Answer (score 5):

@erotavlas as Mafor provided answer which help you resolve your issue please accept his answer.

I am posting extended answer which might help someone else.

Root cause of this Issue was with `selector/labels`.

In `first-service`, `spec.selector` was set to `key: app1`, however in deployment `spec.selector.matchLabels` was set to `run: app1`.

To proper work you need to have the same selectors. So you would need to change in service, spec.selector to `run: app1` or change deployment `spec.selector.matchLabels` to `key: app1`. Same situation with `second-service` and `second-deployment`. More details can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors).

I've tried to use Ingress on Minikube based on [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/) and your YAMLs.

As addition, to use `Ingress` on `Minikube`, `Ingress addon` must be enabled.

```
$ minikube addons list | grep ingress
- ingress: disabled
```

If it's disabled, you have to enable it.

```
$ minikube addons enable ingress
✅  ingress was successfully enabled
```

`targetPort:` is the port the container accepts traffic on / port where application runs inside the pod
`port:` is the abstracted `Service` port, which can be any port other pods use to access the Service.

OP used own images where application was running on ports `5050` and `5000`, for this example I will use GCP hello world on port `8080`. Labels/matchLabels were changed to have the sam value in deployment and service.

**First service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: first-service
spec:
  selector:
    key: app1
  ports:
    - port: 81
      targetPort: 8080

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: first-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      key: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        key: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello1
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080

service/first-service created
deployment.apps/first-deployment created
```

**Second Service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: second-service
spec:
  selector:
    key: app2
  ports:
    - port: 82
      targetPort: 8080

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: second-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      key: app2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        key: app2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello2
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080

service/second-service created
deployment.apps/second-deployment created
```

It crated services as `ClusterIP` type. If need you can use `NodePort` but it's not neccessary.

**Apply Ingress**

Ingress provided in question is enough to tests.

As mentioned in [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#create-an-ingress-resource). You should add minikube ip to host file.

> Note: If you are running Minikube locally, use minikube ip to get the external IP. The IP address displayed within the ingress list will be the internal IP.

In Ubuntu OS it's `/etc/hosts` (need to use sudo to edit). In Windows OS please check [this article](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/edit-host-file-windows-10/)

For my cluster (Using GCE):

```
$ minikube ip
10.132.15.208
```

Added to `hosts` file value:

> 10.132.15.208 demo.local

Below responses.

```
$ curl demo.local/ocr
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: first-deployment-85b75bf4f9-qlzrp
$ curl demo.local/ner
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: second-deployment-5b5bbb7f4-9sbqr
```

However, version with `rewrite` provided by Mafor is more versatile.

In addition, You could also consider use `LoadBalancer` on `Minikube`. 
More information can be found in [Minikube docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tasks/loadbalancer/).

Answer (score 3):

First thing, you don't need `kubectl port-forward`. Ingress is exposed on your minikube ip, port 80.

Second, probably you need some rewrite rules in the ingress configuration. By default, ingress forwards requests "as they are", i.e `demo.local:3000/ocr` is forwarded to `first-service:81/ocr`. Probably it is not what you want, unless first-service is deployed to `/ocr` context.

I guess, you need something like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: demo.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /ocr(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: first-service
          servicePort: 81
      - path: /ner(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: second-service
          servicePort: 82
```

See https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "unless first-service is deployed to /ocr context" . Just to be clear, I'm trying to expose two separate routes one that sends request to one service and another to the other service.  For example first deployment is a container with a flask rest api and I specified the route I want to call as "/ocr"

Comment: What I mean is: does the flask api itself contains the `/ocr` route, or should it be rather called with `/`?

Comment: Flask app contains this `@app.route("/ocr", methods=['POST'])`

Comment: Ok, than ignore my answer, I'll delete it. But the part about `kubectl port-forward` is still valid. And check if you are not trying to connect with https.

Comment: I just tried to add another deployment for hello world using these instructions https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/
 and I added their path to my ingress yaml and I was able to access the service.  When they deploy the service they also expose NodePort `kubectl expose deployment web --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort` - could this be what's wrong with mine, I didn't specify NodePort in the service?

Comment: No, NodePort is not necessary. Try looking into ingress-controller and your apps logs, maybe you will find there something. Are you able to connect to the services directly (`minikube service`)?

Comment: see my edit in original post for output from minikube service

Comment: Right, for `minikube service` you need the NodePort

Comment: I think the selector in my service is wrong, its supposed to be `run: app1` is that right?  when I fixed it, I get a different error instead of 503 I get 404, the requested url doesn't exist on the server.

Comment: OMG its working now, I removed the rewrite `  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` and fixed the selector for both services to match the labels in the deployments. thanks for sticking around to help :) might as well include what i found in your answer