# Deployment pod cannot connect ClusterIP service

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, minikube

I try to expose my server IP by using Ingress.

The server is an Express.js app. It listens at http://localhost:5000 locally when without docker.

Here are my Kubernetes config files:

**server-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: hongbomiao/hongbomiao-server:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: development
```

**server-cluster-ip-service.yaml**

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: server
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

**ingress-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: server-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 5000
```

I got my minikube IP by

```
➜ minikube ip
192.168.64.12
```

When I open 192.168.64.12 in my browser, I got **502 Bad Gateway**.

I got some debug idea after reading https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#kubectl-apply. Here is what I have tried:

```
➜ kubectl get service
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP    5h34m
server-cluster-ip-service   ClusterIP   10.102.5.161   <none>        5000/TCP   4h39m

➜ kubectl get pods
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
server-deployment-bc6777445-pj59f   1/1     Running   0          4h39m

➜ kubectl exec -it server-deployment-bc6777445-pj59f -- sh
/app # apk add --no-cache curl
...
/app # curl 10.102.5.161:5000
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 10.102.5.161 port 5000: Operation timed out
```

It seems my deployment pod has issue connecting ClusterIP service now. Any help will be nice!

Comment: When you say "it listens at http://localhost:5000", is that something that's specifically in your application code (maybe a `listen()` or `bind()` call) or its configuration?  In general if a containerized process listens on a localhost-type address, it won't be reachable from outside its container; you need to set it to listen to 0.0.0.0:5000 instead.  You should see the same behavior if you `docker run` the image without Kubernetes.

Comment: Did you enable `Ingress addon` in your minikube cluster? Could you try your deployment with `Nginx` image or `helloworld` image? Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994578/how-do-i-expose-ingress-to-my-local-machine-minikube-on-windows) might help you.

Comment: @DavidMaze I added more details. It is a Express.js app using listen at port 5000. I met [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65151137/why-does-the-browser-try-to-get-files-through-https-when-the-host-is-0-0-0-0), will report back once I found the solution for that.

Comment: @PjoterS yes, I did enable Ingress addon. However, not there yet. Because my issue is my deployment pod has issue connecting ClusterIP service.

Comment: What is the output of kubectl describe ingress ingress-service? why you are using ClusterIP? ClusterIp is an internal service

Comment: @Lety oh, I am learning it based on an Udemy course. I just happened to make it work. I am not sure which exact step making it work. But I will list the changes I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue is caused by my VPN.

I didn't change anything for the Kubernetes config in my question.

Also, letting the Express.js server explicitly listen at `0.0.0.0` is not necessary neither.

(Note @David Maze's comment under the question about `0.0.0.0` is still valuable)

```
const app = express()
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')))

app.listen(5000); // This just works. No need explicitly change to app.listen(5000, '0.0.0.0');
```

At the time of writing, I was in China. To get rid of the VPN while still using Kubenetes / minikube, I found a way and posted it at GitHub [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5020#issuecomment-739334195).

After turning off the VPN with this workaround solution, everything just works.

Copy my solution using minikube in China here:

---

#### Step 1 - Download the Aliyun version minikube

```sh
curl -Lo minikube https://kubernetes.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/minikube/releases/v1.14.2/minikube-darwin-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin/
```

**Note**: You can find if there is a new version to replace `v1.14.2` in the command above at https://github.com/AliyunContainerService/minikube/wiki#%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%85minikube

#### Step 2 - Start the minikube

```sh
minikube start --image-mirror-country cn \
 --driver=hyperkit \
 --iso-url=https://kubernetes.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.15.0.iso \
 --registry-mirror=https://xxxxxxxx.mirror.aliyuncs.com
```

**Note 1**: You can find latest minikube version at https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md, then replace `v1.15.0` in the command above to newer version.

However, Aliyun's minikube version is a little behind. To verify if a new version exists, you can replace the version in the URL of  https://kubernetes.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.15.0.iso to different new versions, such as `v1.15.1`, and then open it in the browser.

**Note 2**: For the `xxxxxxxx` in the command above, you can find yours at
https://cr.console.aliyun.com/cn-hangzhou/instances/mirrors
(Need register an Aliyun account first)

**Note 3**: You can pass more parameters to this Aliyun version `minikube start`, check at https://github.com/AliyunContainerService/minikube/wiki#%E5%90%AF%E5%8A%A8

In my case, I am using the `driver` hyperkit on macOS, and Aliyun's `iso-url`, `registry-mirror` to speed up.